# does php have any special character classes like [:alnum:] for regex expressions?

Tags: php, regex, expression

Does php have or support any special character classes like [:alnum:] for regex expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the character classes are [listed in the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).